# php imorting file keeps searching on the server

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import

Im having an issue import a .csv file into a php script to add to a mysql server, im local hosting the server and when i test the script the output error says file location does not exist because its searching for the file where the website is stored and not on my desktop where the file actually is.

```
     <form id="import" action="edit.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select BOM .csv file to upload:
    <input name="file" type="file" required="required" id="file" form="import">
    <input name="submit" type="submit" form="import" value="import">
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $file = $_FILES['file'];
        $query = "LOAD DATA INFILE '$file' INTO TABLE `boards` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 LINES";
        $Result = mysql_query($query) OR die(mysql_error());
    }

    ?>
    </form>
```

Does anyone know how to make the actual .csv file upload so I can add it to the sql database?

Comment: How can server access your desktop? It's not possible.

Comment: you want tmp_name from the FILES array, http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php  When a file is uploaded the server first stores the file in the temp folder, then php runs, so the file is uploaded before php.  You just need to pull it from the temp folder and move it to the location you want to store it long term.  Or read it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the issue is that you need the actual name/location of the file.  Now you may think this is the name you gave the file.  However it's actually the name the server gives the copy of the file it has.  This is done to avoid all kinds of file name ( special characters ) nastiness as well as to prevent duplicate names from overwriting.  In PHP and within the super global $_FILES you will find this as the array key `tmp_name`

```
[file] => Array
    (
        [name] => MyFile.jpg
        [type] => image/jpeg
        [tmp_name] => /tmp/php/php6hst32
        [error] => UPLOAD_ERR_OK
        [size] => 98174
    )
```

As you can see the tmp_name ( this mess `/tmp/php/php6hst32` ) is the actual physical file on the server, the name key is the name you gave it ( just a string ) when uploading.  Most times you can use the  `rename()` function to just rename and move it.  such as `rename( $_FILES['tmp_name'], 'path to your upload place/'.$_FILES['name']);`  or `copy()` that will essentially put the name you gave it back after copying/moving the file from ( in this case tmp/php/ ).

You can also use `move_uploaded_file()`  http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Or you can just open it from the temp folder.  There are maybe some security reasons to use move uploaded file over the other options ( or first ), but that's apost for another day.